# Create Number Counter that increments by 1 per the last number assigned

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking to assign a variable called "quoteIdentifier" to an incrementing integer. My use case is that everytime someone submits a quote to my firestore database, the quote automatically will assign an integer as an ID of sorts.

So if my first user entered their information into the form - it would assign integer 1
then the second user enters their information, and the code references the last integer assigned, and increments up by 1.. so something like lastEntryInt ++. Is this even possible to reference a last assigned value? Perhaps I read from the firestore field the last assigned? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious why you need an incrementing integer that needs to be synced across all your users? Could you not just assign a random unique id, upload to FireStore and then query the amount of users based on number of IDs? Or is there a reason it needs to increment by 1?

Comment: I'm with swigganicks that such counters in general are not ideal, since they become points of contention in multi-user applications. That said: transactions are precisely for such "read current value and update" operations. You can read about them here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions. Since this is literally covered in the docs, I'm going to close your question as too broad. Feel free to post again if you have trouble implementing the transaction.

Comment: The reason i need it, is because i am using that to reference a random pull of a quote. I have used a previous post in regards to random numbers and firestore queries, but being that my numbers assigned are ranged between 1-5000 once i run the code to generate a random quote, sometimes i get duplicates and don't even get the others in the database. This is due to the fact that some are auto assigning a random int in the 4000's as compared to others which may be assigned in the 400's So I am trying to get it so that i know the random pull will be in a reasonable range. make sense?

Comment: I think you should look into cloud functions. You could have a cloud function assign the incrementing value and keep track (in a separate document) the current value. With the current value, you can write a better random quote chooser function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using incremented numbers, why don't you use a random key generator like this:

```
func returnRandomKey(usrname: String) -> String {
    let key = String(arc4random()) + usrname 
    return key
}
```

This could also work

Additionally, if you want to track the number of users, you can use an incrementing variable

Comment: Great idea! Thank you